# How to select all checkbox based on custom checkbox in filterTemplate in JsGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jsgrid

Here i am trying to check all checkbox for using custom checkbox we can see here filterTemplate section and selectAll or unselectAll these are Bold for getting my point

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/MerchandiseList/GetMerchant"
    }).done(function (data) {
        //$("#leftMenu").hide();
        //reloadpage(data);

        var MyDateField = function (config) {
            jsGrid.Field.call(this, config);
        };

        MyDateField.prototype = new jsGrid.Field({
            sorter: function (date1, date2) {
                return new Date(date1) - new Date(date2);
            },
            itemTemplate: function (value) {
                if (value == "")
                    return "";
                else {

                    var date = new Date(value).toDateString()
                    //var date = new Date(value).toDateString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                    //return new Date(value).toDateString();
                    //return value;
                    var d = new Date(date),
                    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                    day = '' + d.getDate(),
                    year = d.getFullYear();
                    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
                    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
                    var df = [month, day, year].join('/');
                    //var df = [year, month, day].join('/');
                    date = df;
                    return date;
                }
            },

            insertTemplate: function (value) {

                return this._insertPicker = $("<input>").datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
            },

            editTemplate: function (value) {
                if (value == "")
                    return this._editPicker = $("<input>").datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });
                else {
                    return this._editPicker = $("<input>").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date(value));
                }
            },

            insertValue: function () {
                if (this._insertPicker.datepicker("getDate") != null)
                    return this._insertPicker.datepicker("getDate");         //.toISOString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                //else
                //    return this._insertPicker.datepicker("getDate");
            },

            editValue: function () {
                //debugger
                if (this._editPicker.datepicker("getDate") != null)
                    //.toISOString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                    return this._editPicker.datepicker("getDate");
                //return this._editPicker.datepicker("getDate").toISOString();
                //else
                //    return this._editPicker.datepicker("getDate");
            }
        });

        jsGrid.fields.myDateField = MyDateField;

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "50%",
            width: "100%",
            filtering: true,
            editing: true,
            editButtonTooltip: "Edit",
            inserting: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            autoload: true,
            pageButtonCount: 5,
            pageSize: 15,
            overflow: scroll,
            confirmDeleting: true,
            deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the merchandise?",
            //refreshtext: "Refresh",
            //onRefreshed: function (args) { },
            selecting: true,

            controller: db,

            fields: [
                {


                    **filterTemplate**: function (_, item) { // how to get all grid items here? This return only single item but empty in Filter row.
                        return $("<input>").attr("type", "checkbox")
                        .prop("checked", $.inArray(item, selectedItems) > -1)
                        .on("change", function () {
                            $(this).is(":checked") ? selectAll(item) : unselectAll(item);
                        });
                    },
                    itemTemplate: function (_, item) {
                        return $("<input>").attr("type", "checkbox")
                                .prop("checked", $.inArray(item, selectedItems) > -1)
                                .on("change", function () {
                                    $(this).is(":checked") ? selectItem(item) : unselectItem(item);
                                });
                    },
                    align: "center",
                    width: 50,
                    sorting: false,
                    filtering: false
                },
                { type: "control" },

                {
                    name: "Source", type: "text", width: 120, title: "Vendor"
                },
                {
                    name: "Description", type: "text", width: 210,
                    validate: { message: "Description is required!", validator: function (value) { return value != ""; } }
                },
                {
                    name: "ModelNumber", type: "text", width: 120, title: "Model#/Item"
                },
                { name: "SKU", type: "text", width: 90 },
                { name: "SKU2", type: "text", width: 90 },
                { name: "Comments", type: "text", width: 200 },
                { name: "strReceiveDate", type: "myDateField", width: 80, align: "center", title: "Received" },
                { name: "Location", type: "select", items: data.loc, valueField: "LocationID", textField: "Description", width: 100 },
                { name: "Barcode", width: 80 },
                { name: "BarcodePrinted", type: "checkbox", title: "Barcode Printed", sorting: false },
                //{ name: "strLastUpdatedDate", type: "myDateField", width: 80, title: "Last Updated" },
                { name: "strLastUsedDate", type: "myDateField", width: 80, title: "Last Updated" },
                { name: "DamageCode", type: "select", items: data.dam, valueField: "CodeID", textField: "CodeValue", title: "Damage" },
                { name: "strCreatedDate", editable: false, width: 80, title: "Created Date", type: "myDateField" },
                { name: "strShipDate", type: "myDateField", myCustomProperty: "bar", width: 80, title: "Ship Date" },
                { name: "strConsumeDate", type: "myDateField", myCustomProperty: "bar", width: 80, title: "Consume Date" },
                { name: "PendingShipment", type: "checkbox", title: "Pending", sorting: false, width: 60 },
                { name: "Donated", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Donated", sorting: false, width: 60 },
                { name: "ReturnRequested", type: "checkbox", title: "Return Requested", sorting: false },
                { name: "ReturnTo", type: "text", width: 150, title: "Return To" },
                { name: "Quantity", type: "number", width: 50, title: "Qty" },
                { name: "GroupName", type: "text", width: 150, title: "Group Name" },
                { name: "CustomerID", width: 100, title: "Customer ID" }
            ],
        });

        var selectedItems = [];
        var selectItem = function (item) {

            document.getElementById("hdn").value = document.getElementById("hdn").value + "," + item.Barcode;
            selectedItems.push(item);
            //debugger

            var $grid = $("#jsGrid");
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", false);
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", true);
        };

        var unselectItem = function (item) {
            selectedItems = $.grep(selectedItems, function (i) {
                //debugger
                return i !== item;
            });
            var value = document.getElementById("hdn").value;
            value = value.replace(item.Barcode, "");
            document.getElementById("hdn").value = value;

            var $grid = $("#jsGrid");
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", false);
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", true);
        };

        var **selectAll** = function (item) {                
            document.getElementById("hdn").value = document.getElementById("hdn").value + "," + item.Barcode;
            selectedItems.push(item);


            var $grid = $("#jsGrid");
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", false);
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", true);
        };

        var **unselectAll** = function (item) {
            selectedItems = $.grep(selectedItems, function (i) {
                //debugger
                return i !== item;
            });
            var value = document.getElementById("hdn").value;
            value = value.replace(item.Barcode, "");
            document.getElementById("hdn").value = value;

            var $grid = $("#jsGrid");
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", false);
            $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", true);
        };           

    });

});
```

```
here the output image here     [https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMfwn.png][1]
```

But noting happens can any one help me

Comment: Yes i got this solution....yupi

Comment: Using This Code

Comment: var selectAll = function (item) {                          
                var grid = $("#jsGrid").data("JSGrid");  var k= Number("0");              
                selectedItems = $.grep(grid.data, function (i) {if (k<= 15)
                    {k++; document.getElementById("Braja_" + i.Barcode).checked = true;
                        document.getElementById("hdn").value = document.getElementById("hdn").value + "," + i.Barcode;
                        selectedItems.push(i.Barcode);
                        return i === i.Barcode;
                    }});  };

Comment: var unselectAll = function (item) {
                document.getElementById("hdn").value = "";

                var grid = $("#jsGrid").data("JSGrid");

                selectedItems = $.grep(grid.data, function (i) {
                    //debugger
                    document.getElementById("Braja_" + i.Barcode).checked = false;
                    return i !== i.Barcode;
                });

                var $grid = $("#jsGrid");
                $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", false);
                $grid.jsGrid("option", "editing", true);
            };

Comment: use this code....